# Validation loss >> train loss, same data, binary classifier

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I implemented [this paper's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04046) neural net, with some differences (img below), for EEG classification; `train_on_batch` performance is excellent, with very low loss - but `test_on_batch` performance, though on *same data*, is poor: the net seems to always predict '1', most of the time:

```
       TRAIN (loss,acc)   VAL (loss,acc)
'0' -- (0.06269842,1)     (3.7652588,0)
'1' -- (0.04473557,1)     (0.3251827,1)
```

Data is fed as 30-sec segments (12000 timesteps) (10 mins per dataset) from 32 (= batch_size) datasets at once (img below)

Any remedy?

---

**Troubleshooting attempted**:

1. Disabling dropout
2. Disabling all regularizers (except batch-norm)
3. Randomly, val_acc('0','1') = (~.90, ~.12) - then back to (0,1)

**Additional details**:

- Keras 2.2.4 (TensorFlow backend), Python 3.6, Spyder 3.3.4 via Anaconda
- CuDNN LSTM stateful
- CNNs pretrained, LSTMs added on afterwards (and both trained)
- `BatchNormalization` after every CNN & LSTM layer
- `reset_states()` applied between different datasets
- [squeeze_excite_block](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-squeeze-excite-network/blob/master/se.pyom/BXtHS.png) inserted after every but last CNN block

---

**UPDATE**:
Progress was made; `batch_normalization` and `dropout` are the major culprits. Major changes:

- Removed LSTMs, GaussianNoise, SqueezeExcite blocks (img below)
- Implemented batch_norm [patch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965)
- Added `sample_weights` to reflect class imbalance - varied between 0.75 and 2.
- Trained with various warmup schemes for both MaxPool and Input dropouts

Considerable improvements were observed - but not nearly total. Train vs. validation loss behavior is truly bizarre - flipping class predictions, and bombing the exact same datasets it had *just trained on*:

[image]

Also, `BatchNormalization` outputs during train vs. test time differ considerably (img below)

---

**UPDATE 2:** All other suspicions were ruled out: **BatchNormalization** is the culprit. Using Self-Normalizing Networks (SNNs) with SELU & AlphaDropout in place of BatchNormalization yields stable and consistent results.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would recommend 1) plot training accuracy and training loss along epochs. If accuracy gets to 100% early or training loss is falls too quickly ramp up your regularization 2) if overfitting (more likely) - increase learning rate, if underfitting - decrease learning

Comment: Cited statistics persist across all datasets; train and validation sets are _same_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inadvertently left in one non-standardized sample (in a batch of 32), with `sigma=52` - which severely disrupted the `BN` layers; post-standardizing, I no longer observe a strong discrepancy between train & inference modes - if anything, any differences are difficult to spot.

Furthermore, the entire preprocessing was very fault - after redoing correctly, the problem no longer recurs. As a debug tip, try identifying whether any particular train dataset sharply alters layer activations during inference.